# Send simple serial strings with minicom (or other tool)

Tags: command-line, serial-port

I'm trying to use minicom (or any other terminal program available over ssh) to send and receive (and possibly log) very simple serial commands to my microcontroller.

I set up minicom to receive from my tty device and setup the baudrate. I have a second usb to tty converter that I'm testing with, where I use a GUI like Cutecom or Hterm. I can send simple "test" strings and they show up in minicom, however I'm not able to send an answer from the terminal. Whatever I type it doesn't show up in my GUI Terminal. I get a bunch of garbage when I'm closing minicom, but thats it.

I already tried this solution by pressing CTRL+J but that didnt do anything either.

Am I using the wrong tool? Is there something simpler thats analog to CuteCom or Hterm just for the Terminal?

Heres the minicom Screen: (the test came from my hterm serial device)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Press the "E" key when in minicom to enable local echo and try again. Local echo is an option because sometimes it results in double characters being printed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the serial terminal in the Arduino IDE to be soooo much more intuitive and simpler than minicom. It works on any serial port, despite the name suggesting it's only for Arduino boards, e.g. I have used it on STM32 boards no problem. The only feature it lacks is the ability to send terminal characters, e.g. hitting Ctrl-L would ideally send a form feed character (0xC), but it is a shortcut for some IDE operation.